# DialogBoxParam and GetOpenFileName

Tags: c++, winapi, getopenfilename

First of all, here's my config:

```
VS2010/Debug/C++ Win32 Project/Vista Home Premium
```

Invoking `GetOpenFileName` via a button (`CreateWindow`) in a window (`CreateWindow`) gets me no problem: The Open Dialog works fine, I can click, navigate to another folder etc...

Now, I replace my `CreateWindow` with a `DialogBoxParam` (that should call `CreateWindow` behind the scenes), with the same `(DLGPROC)WndProc` and invoke the same `GetOpenFileName`. Here, the Open dialog is behaving strangely: looks like only the mouse double-click works (= populating `ofn.lpstrFile` and closing the Open dialog). Not able to click the Open and Cancel buttons and not able to navigate.

Anyone having experienced this before? Any known reasons for the Open dialog to kind of "freeze". Belong to a parent or not (`ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd; ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;`) gives the same problem.

Thanks
N

Comment: Post some code, and maybe we can help.  Vague descriptions of code are just that: vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

> with the same (DLGPROC)WndProc

That's your bug. A dialog procedure and a window procedure are not the same thing. They follow different rules, and if you follow WndProc rules when you should be following DlgProc rules, then bad things will happen.

Comment: The classic "cast to fix it" solution [strikes again](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) :)

Comment: Ok, you are right. A  DefWindowProc is not a DefDlgProc . Thank you. (+1 if i could)